# Rails: assign_attributes fails because of a duplicated attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an **Order** model related to the database table **orders** which has the column **pay_type:integer**, but later on a **pay_types** table was added and the **Order** model was modified to look like this:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pay_type
  ...
end
```

which means that now the **Order** model has 2 attributes with the name **pay_type**. I can still read the one related to the table column by using the **read_attribute** method:

```
order = Order.first
order.pay_type # nil
order.read_attribute(:pay_type) # 1
```

But when I try to assign to the latter by using the **assign_attributes** method like this:

```
order.assign_attributes(pay_type: 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (PayType(#14340) expected, got 2 which is an instance of Integer(#5000))
```

I know I could just change the name of the **pay_type** attribute on the **Order** model like this:

```
belongs_to pay_type_something, class_name: :PayType
```

and the repetition would be gone, but I just want to know: is there any way to assign a value to my first **pay_type** attribute without changing any names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`[]=`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) or [`write_attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute).

```
order[:pay_type] = 2 # or
order.write_attribute(:pay_type, 2)
```

But those methods are protected what limits their use cases. As you already notice best would be to rename the attribute or the association.